# onClick on Cardview get from firebase

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I did this at my newsviewholder:

```
    public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    Context context;

    public NewsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetalleFragment.class);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setTitular(String titular) {
        TextView post_titular = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        post_titular.setText(titular);
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
    }
}
```

The problem its when I do onClick in the cardview It throws the next error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo, PID: 5200
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo/es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Fragments.DetalleFragment};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224) at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183) at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507) at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475) at
>   es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo.Models.NewsViewHolder$1.onClick(NewsViewHolder.java:32)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

And Ive in my AndroidManifest.xml defined the new activity, but I dont know how to solve this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="es.laramira.atellez.moroninfo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityDetalle"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Ive tried a lot of answer found in Stackoverflow and in other sites but I cant solve this...

Comment: You are trying to start a Fragment as Activity (which seems to be a Fragment with the name DetalleFragment.class). This can't work, the exception explains the problem. If you simply want to start an Activity with the layout of the Fragment, create an Activity and use the layout of the Fragment in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting the Fragment, instead of your activity.

```
new Intent(view.getContext(), DetalleFragment.class);
```

But you can't use context.startActivity for a fragment.

If you want to start your "ActivityDetalle", as I see in your 
Manifest, replace the call with

```
new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityDetalle.class);
```

Edit:

If you want to start the activity from a context, that does not belong to
an activity, you have to add the intent flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Context c;` is never initialised so

```
View v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.activity_detalle,parent,false);
            return new NewsViewHolder(v);
```

returns `null`.

**Update.**

As I understood you just want to assign `onClickListener` to an item.

Creating and setting another adapter won't solve your problem. I would say that is totally wrong way.

To add `onClickListener` to your card you need to edit `NewsViewHolder`:

```
public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
...
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your stuff
    }
...
});
```

**Update.**

Unfortunately, stackoverflow is a place where you can get an answer for concrete question, rather than "I insert some code, it still does not work". It is a waste of time.
First of all you  must learn how to read [logs and debug](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Debugging-Exceptions-within-your-App).

Here are some resources to start with:

https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853
https://commonsware.com/Android/

Comment: How can I initialize it?? I made a constructor with parameter context. But I throw the same error

Comment: Check if your view is inflated and not _null_ in `onCreateViewHolder`.

Comment: I cant the application stop when I implement the adapter

Comment: Do you mean that you have an exception on initialising your adapter class?

Comment: You provide just the beginning of exception in the answer under Nikhya's answer.

Comment: Sorry!! Question edited and I provide the complete exception

Comment: Now `RecyclerView rv` is `null`, while you call `rv.setAdapter(adapter)`. Check your recycler id.

Comment: My recycler id is news_list and its inside a relative layout? Can this be a possible problem? Its name is the same which Im trying to findviewbyid

Comment: `(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.news_list)` returns `null`. Attach the code that calls `findViewById()` and your layout xml.

Comment: Ive just edited the question and show the calls to findviewbyid and my layout where I put the recyclerView

Comment: I am pretty sure that the xml you have provided is not `activity_main.xml`, but something else. However that is clear now why `findViewById()` returns `null`. First, fragment is not created by that time. Second, you should not init fragment's UI from activity, but from fragment.

Comment: On my project, I have fragments where I show the list at the activity_main.xml I show the DrawerLayout with a Navigation View(Hamburger Menu). Ive just implemented the adapter on the class which is relation with the default fragment, but It throw the same error.

Comment: I don't understand. Move `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.news_list);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);` in fragment class.

Comment: Ive just edited the question trying to explain you what i did, and what Im trying to do

Comment: But you already set adapter `onStart()`: `mNewsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);`. And than you want to set it again on another one?

Comment: `RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.news_list);` is wrong, rv will still be null. It should be `rootview.findViewById(R.id.news_list);`

Comment: At the first adapter I give datas to the cardview and I want to take this cardview(when user make onclick), open an activity and show inside the other activity the headline, image and body of a new

Comment: I try it, and it throw other diferent error: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type I think this is easy to solve but thanks by your help

Comment: Before trying this solution, I did that ... But I throw other error, I show you editing the question.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetalleFragment.class);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);` you try to start activity providing the fragment to intent's constructor, this will not work. Please, read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the context in adapter either via calling a constructor like

```
public MyAdapter(Context c) {
        this.c=c;
```

}

and call the constructor in your activity when you are initialising adapter  like

```
MyAdapter adaoter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

so that your Context will not be empty!

Comment: Ive made this and Its throw the other error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: initialise your adapter variable inside your activity where you are binding your adapter with recycler view

Comment: I initialized it using:        'MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.news_list);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter); ' It throw the same error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: make sure that u have implemented a parameterized constructor in your adapter class like i explained in the answer. and pass the values that you are going to use in that constructor